# Error during apt update: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

When I try to update by using command `sudo apt update`
I get this error:

```
E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Before this error started to happen, I was trying to install `grafana`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list
```

**From comments:**

**1.** `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list`

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.gpg] https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
deb https://packages.grafana.com/enterprise/deb stable main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.gpg] https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/enterprise/deb stable main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/enterprise/deb beta main
```

**2.** GnuPG info:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.fGvGNgllIZ
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
           CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
Please report bugs to <bugs.gnupg.org>.
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things have apparently gone wrong, when comparing to the [official installation guide](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/debian/).

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list` should only have a single line, depending on which Grafana version you choose.

The different options are (assuming the key is: `/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key`):

Enterprise Edition, stable releases:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/enterprise/deb stable main
```

Enterprise Edition, beta releases:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/enterprise/deb beta main
```

OSS Edition, stable releases:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
```

OSS Edition, beta releases:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grafana.key] https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb beta main
```

Add only one of the lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list`, and remove everything else from the file.